# How to draw this figure?

Tags: equations, framed

The figure in the attached image contains mathematical formulae, some of which are aligned, also it is rounded by a box, could anyone tell me how to draw that?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: You can use the package `empheq`

Comment: It's not clear what about this image you want to reproduce. Also, we discourage "How do I draw this?" questions. Could you maybe edit the question to be more like "How can I achieve <something>?" where <something> is some specific aspect of the image. We can help with _that_...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is to put something in a box, you could use the `mdframed` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
And now, some framed maths:
\begin{mdframed}
  \begin{equation}
    e^{i\pi}+1=0
  \end{equation}
Some more text.
\begin{align}
  \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta &= 1 \\
  \sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= \cos \theta
\end{align}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image: framed maths]

This package has the advantage that it breaks across pages and fancy stuff like that. Also, changing the padding and margins is easier than with the `framed` package, for example. `mdframed` has key-value syntax for changing things. Neat.

Comment: If you want the box to float, place it in a `figure` environment. From what I can see of the image it looks like that box is in a float...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't understand well about the OP's terminologies "figure" and "draw". These 2 words in the OP's question caused me (and others) to get a wrong impression about your problem.

### Option 1

Are the framed equations provided as an external image file? If it is so, then you should reproduce the equations and the framed manually as explained in Seamus's answer. 
Reproducing the equations gives you another benefit, i.e., you can take advantage of equation labels.

### Option 2

But if you insist on importing the existing image, then use the `\includegraphics{yourequation}` macro from `graphicx` package as follows. You cannot get the benefit that I explained in the first option. In other words, the equation labels in the image will be unusable.

The following code assumes that your image has been framed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{yourequations}
\caption{your caption}
\end{figure}
% other stuffs go here...
\end{document}
```

If your image has not been framed yet, then you need `\fbox` to frame it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\fbox{%
\includegraphics[scale=1]{yourequations}}
\caption{your caption}
\end{figure}
% other stuffs go here...
\end{document}
```